# equality in noncommutative Hölder inequality

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, fa.functional-analysis, reference-request

Let $1\leq p,q,r\leq \infty$ such that $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}$. Let $S_p$ denote the Schatten space. For any $x\in S_p$ and any $y\in S_q$ we have
$$
||xy||_{S_r} \leq ||x||_{S_p}||y||_{S_q}
$$
(noncommutative Hölder's inequality).

Does it exists necessary and sufficient conditions on $x,y$ in order to have an equality in this inequality?

More generally, I ask the same question replacing $S_p$ by the noncommutative $L_p$-space $L_p(M)$ associated with a semifinite von Neumann algebra $M$ equipped with a normal semifinite faithful trace $\tau$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The necessary and sufficient condition is that $|x|^p$ and $|y^*|^q$ are proportional. This can be deduced from [Dixmier's paper](http://archive.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1953__81__9_0.pdf) (although it is not clearly stated that way there; it is based on Proposition 8). It probably also appears in more modern treatments (Nelson, Terp, Haagerup, Hiai, Kosaki, etc.) but I don't have the sources here to check that.

Comment: You probably mean that $|x|^p$ and $|y^*|^p$ are proportional.

Comment: Right. Thanks, Mikael.  I'll correct it right away.